# How someone can reach my NAS on my local network?

Tags: networking, router, ssh, nas

I have a local network with no DMZ enabled and a Synology. For the past few days I keep receiving this king of e-mails from my NAS:

> The IP address [51.91.158.54] experienced 10 failed attempts when attempting to log into SSH running on hodor within 5 minutes, and was blocked at Wed Apr 15 06:46:01 2020.

However:

- My router has no NAT neither DMZ configuration set.
- The DDNS is enabled on my Synology, but in the Router Configuration both SSH and Management UI fail when I hit the `Test Connection` button.

How it is possible someone can access my NAS from the outside?

Comment: Do you have IPv6 enabled in your local network? If you do, then all your devices are exposed to the internet. Another and worse possibility is that one of your internal devices is infected.

Comment: Nop IPv6 is disabled on my local network. And my NAS is mentioning 51.91.158.54 which is IPv4 and not a local address.

Comment: Yet you are being attacked by someone renting a cloud server from OVH in France. If it's coming from outside, then it's going through your router. I suggest to reboot the router, and check ALL parameters and also look for firmware update.

Comment: I did a `nmap -O` with my public IP but I found no opened port...

Comment: Maybe the router is compromised?

Comment: `nmap` doesn't check for infected router.

Comment: @harrymc What is an infected router that is not opened to any port?

Comment: The router is a specialized computer, usually Linux, so can be infected just like any other computer. Some routers have known vulnerabilities that allow an attacker to install its own software and attack, or let through an attack, to the internal network. Rebooting it may destroy the infection, or if not then a factory reset will certainly do that. A firmware update may close off the vulnerability. Not sure that this is what's happening, but is worth checking.